# How to write all domain name redirects in one line

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I think it should be possible to write most domain name redirects in one line, 
can you tell me if you think this is correct?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.myexample\.fr|myexample\.fr|www\.myexample\.com|myexample\.com)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I can't test as I can't afford the website to crash, even for one minute, too many people are working on it.

Thank you,
i'm impatient to read your comments

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the conditions like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.my-example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

i.e. is host is not `www.my-example.com` in request then redirect to `www.my-example.com`.

Comment: Kudos for solving the issue properly instead of answering the question. A negative match is far better than individually matching all aliases, which should only appear in `ServerAlias` directives, thus prefiltering before the condition.

Comment: hello,thank you and what about the mispelling "myexample.com" with and without the www + with the .fr ?

Comment: Mis-spelled domains like `myexample.com` won't even reach to your server  since you don't have DNS pointing to your IP for bad host names. And this rule has negative condition i.e. `!=www.my-example.com` which means if  host is not `www.my-example.com` and will cover all the cases.

Comment: Let me know if you have further doubts on this.